# Kali Linux update stuck at '0% [working]'

Tags: linux, debian, kali-linux

I have installed Kali Linux and I have updated it many times using the `sudo apt-get update` command successfully, but, according to my memory, after installing KDE or AMD packages the update command doesn't work. It downloads some packages, it suddenly stops and shows '0% [Working]' without giving any error or without exiting the update process:

```
Get:23 http://ftp.yzu.edu.tw/Linux/kali kali-rolling/non-free amd64 Contents (deb) [839 kB]
0% [Working]
```

I tried sudo `apt-get clean` and `rm /var/lib/apt/lists/*`, but that didn't fix this error and now there are no packages in `/var/lib/apt/lists`.

How can I fix this? This is the output I see on my terminal:

[image]

Comment: remove the offline repository

Comment: so how should i do it? you think this happen because of offline repositories?

Comment: Choosing a different server in the `Software Updater` probably may solve this issue.

Comment: Kali Rolling has only one URL in the sources.list file to get its repositories. so how should i use a different server? @mook765

Comment: It seems there was a change in the update procedure maybe a week ago and after that change i had the same issue in Kubuntu and in UbuntuStudio. Changing to a different server solved this for me. I don't have KaliLinux installed, so I don't know how many servers they offer. When I double-click `sources.list` the software-updater will open and then I click the small triangle to choose a server, then I choose `others`, that opens a list of servers for many countries. But as I said I am on Ubuntu-based distros, Kali is Debian based and might be a bit different.

Comment: i changed the mirror and tested but same output is given. i think the problem is in executing the downloaded packages. because i can see everything is downloading correctly. after that when they are executed, it is not happening. still i could not find a solution. so please help